# how to use animation with ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-animate, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list which I iterate over by using ng-repeat: and the user can interact with thte list items by using up-arrow and down-arrow icons and on click of them i simply change the order of the element in the "list" this is what angular suggests change the model and the changes automatically reflect in the view.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
{{item.name}} 
<div class="icon-up-arrow" ng-click="moveUp($index);"></div> 
<div class="icon-down-arrow" ng-click="moveDown($index);"></div>
</div>
```

Logic in moveUp:-

```
$scope.moveUp= function(position){
 var temp=list[position-1];
 list[position-1]=list[position];
 list[position=temp];
};
```

the above code works completely fine and similar is the logic for shifting the item down. But the problem that i want to resolve is how do i put animation? I know angular takes care of binding view and model on its own but is there any way to put in animation as the view is updated on pressing up an down arrow icons?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Following on from Marcel's comment: in AngularJS 1.2 you don't need to use the `ng-animate` directive. Instead:

1. Include`angular-animate[-min].js`.
2. Make your module depend on `ngAnimate`.
3. Define your transitions in CSS using [classes like `.ng-enter` and `.ng-enter-active`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate).
4. Use `ng-repeat` as you normally would.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="foo">
    <!-- Set up controllers etc, and then: -->
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('foo', ['ngAnimate']);
// controllers not shown
```

CSS:

```
li {
    opacity: 1;
}
li.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
li.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Demo in (someone else's) Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZljRItnL986V821M7Ck?p=preview).

See the [docs for $animate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) for details on the progression through the various CSS classes.

Comment: It's also a good idea to restrict animation to just the things you're interested in - otherwise you can end up with elements hanging around for a few extra seconds if you haven't defined the appropriate CSS classes. See [$animateProvider.classNameFilter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/provider/$animateProvider#classNameFilter)

Comment: I found this http://plnkr.co/edit/oCLzLHbDLtNT8G8rKFJS?p=preview more helpful example which gives idea of animation when element is inserted at any index.

Answer (score 6):

Check this link http://www.nganimate.org/

1. You need to declare the ng-animate attribute to an element that have another directive that changes the DOM

   ```
   div ng-repeat="item in itens" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}"
   ```
2. You need to add css transitions or animation.

   ```
   .animate-enter {
      -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
      transition: 1s linear all;
      opacity: 0;
   }
   .animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
      opacity: 1;
   }
   ```

You can check plnkr example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/VfWsyg9d7xROoiW9HHRM

Comment: I think the ng-animate directive is deprecated in AngularJS 1.2.
For a current ng-repeat example check out this link http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-ngrepeat

Most of CSS from nganimate.org though is still a good way to get started.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing the last answer, there is the ng-move class for animations when order is changed:

```
li {
    opacity: 1;
}
li.ng-move {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
li.ng-move-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Last [documentation here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate).

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t wish to use ‘ngAnimate’ module because of reduce the plugins count, you can archive the simple transition effect by using ng-init and custom directives.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="item" item-init>{{item.name}}</li>

.item{
    opacity:0;

   -webkit-transition: all linear 300ms;
   transition: all linear 300ms;
}
.item.visible{
    opacity:1;
}


myApp.directive('itemInit', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.initItem(element);
    };
});
```

In you controller

```
$scope.initItem = function(el){
    $timeout(function(){
        angular.element(el).addClass('visible');
    },0);
}
```