# Animate ng-click without jquery/js

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a ribbon with some div's in a row within. If it overlaps and you can not see everything, I show an arrow left from the ribbon and an arrow right of the ribbon. With this arrows I can scroll throught the ribbon infinite in the circle (direction left or right).

My codes lookes like this:

```
<div class="arrow" ng-click="list.push(list.shift())>&larr;</div>
<div class="ribbon">
    <div class="ribbonItem" ng-repeat="item in list">
        {{ item.Name }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow" ng-click="list.unshift(list.pop())>&rarr;</div>
```

This works, but it's without an animation and increased. It also needs much clicks to scroll throught. How can I implement an animation without using jquery or js and just do it with this ng-click. I tried it with a transition on the css-classes ng-enter/ng-leave of my ng-repeat, but it does'nt work: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat (look at "Animations").

Has someone an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question : [how to use animation with ng-repeat in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580599/how-to-use-animation-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Go through this link it might help you:
http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move