# Angular ng-animate only animate on data change

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that i would like to have animate when a row is either added or removed. I have a function calling an angular controller every 2 seconds to get the data. Everything works, however the table is animating every 2 seconds. The whole thing fades in every 2 seconds. I would like only the new row added or removed to fade in or out. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<h1>
Scans
</h1>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ScansController" >   
    <table id="scansTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ScanId</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Time Stamp</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="scan in Scans">
                <td>
                    {{scan.scanId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.firstName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.lastName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.timeStamp}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr {
opacity: 1;
}
tr.ng-enter {
-webkit-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
opacity: 0;
}
tr.ng-enter-active {
opacity: 1;
}

</style>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

myApp.service('dataService', function ($http) {

this.getData = function () {

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/scans/'
    });
}
});

myApp.controller('ScansController', function ($scope, dataService, $timeout) {

$scope.Scans = [];

function fetchData() {
    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {
        $scope.Scans = result.data;
        $timeout(function () { fetchData(); }, 2000);
    });
}

fetchData();

});
```

Comment: Have you loaded `ngAnimate` in your module as a dependency? e.g. `angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);`

Comment: @papakia i didnt have that before, but i just added it and it is still not animating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use animation with ng-repeat in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580599/how-to-use-animation-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Comment: @papakia Yes this solved the animation, however there is a new issue. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the controller to be the following, and got rid of the animate css. Now my table only animates on data change, but this is only if the array length is different.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('dataService', function ($http) {

this.getData = function () {

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/scans/'
    });
}
});

myApp.controller('ScansController', function ($scope, dataService, $timeout) {

$scope.Scans = [];
$scope.NewScans = [];

function fetchData() {
    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {

        $scope.Scans = result.data;
        $("#scansTable").removeClass('animated bounceIn');           
    });
}

function fetchNewData() {
    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {

        $scope.NewScans = result.data;

        if ($scope.Scans.length != $scope.NewScans.length)
        {               
            $("#scansTable").addClass('animated bounceIn');
            $scope.Scans = $scope.NewScans              
        }

        $timeout(function () { fetchNewData(); }, 1000);
    });
}

fetchData();
fetchNewData();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use merge.

Change this line:

```
$scope.NewScans = result.data;
```

to:

```
angular.merge($scope.NewScans, result.data);
```

Doing it this way, you will keep the reference to the $scope.NewScans and only its changed content will get the update.